# How to convert escaped Json into regular Json or variable?

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I'm using Ansible to pull the contents of a JSON file from Bitbucket. The problem is the content is escaped JSON so I can't use it in a variable or parse it, etc. Here's an example of what I get back from Bitbucket:

```json
{
    "json": {
      "lines": [
            {
            "text": "    \"AWS\": {"
            },
            {
            "text": "        \"S3\": {"
            },
            {
            "text": "            \"Bucket\": \"my-s3-bucket\","
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```yaml
json_file.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('\n') | from_json
```

or

```yaml
json_file.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('\n') | to_json
```

After the `join()` (before `from/to_json`), the content looks something like this:

```
{\\n    \"AWS\": {\\n        \"S3\": {\\n            \"Bucket\": \"my-s3-bucket\"\\n            }\\n    }\\n  }
```

Neither of above filters return usable Json. As soon as I try to access an item in the Json I get `VARIABLE IS UNDEFINED` or I get `Unexpected failure during module execution: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`.

So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems here.

### Input is not valid JSON

If we extract the text in your example, we don't get a valid JSON document.  We get:

```
    "AWS": {"
        "S3": {"
            "Bucket": "my-s3-bucket"
```

That by itself is a fragment of a JSON document. In order to test out a solution, we would need minimally the equivlanet of:

```
{
    "AWS": {"
        "S3": {"
            "Bucket": "my-s3-bucket"
        }
    }
}
```

### Filter does not result in valid JSON

When you write:

```
json_file.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('\n') | to_json
```

You are not joining lines with a newline. You are joining lines with the literal two-character sequence `\n`. That results in a document that is not valid JSON.

The simplest solution is just to join on `""` instead.

### The solution

Taking both of the above into account, we can put together something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    document: {
      "json": {
        "lines": [
              {
              "text": "{"
              },
              {
              "text": "    \"AWS\": {"
              },
              {
              "text": "        \"S3\": {"
              },
              {
              "text": "            \"Bucket\": \"my-s3-bucket\""
              },
              {
                "text": "}}}"
                }
          ]
      }
    }

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        json: "{{ document.json.lines | map(attribute='text') | join('') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Bucket: {{ json.AWS.S3.Bucket }}"
```

Which produces as output:

```
PLAY [Testing] *****************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Bucket: my-s3-bucket"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the help!